# Accepting Calendar invites not showing in calendar

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, calendar

My company uses Gmail as our email and calendar. When I receive an invitation and accept it on my phone (Samsung Galaxy S4) it never puts it in my Google calendar. I have to wait until I get to my computer to accept. This occurred on my S2 as well. A co-worker has the same problem. When I accept it opens my browser and shows that I've accepted but never makes it to my calendar. Any ideas on how to fix this?